# JQuery countdown after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, countdowntimer

Hi guys I've created a jQuery countdown but I want it to stay counting even if I refresh the page, here it is the source code:

```
function JBCountDown(settings) {
var glob = settings;

function deg(deg) {
    return (Math.PI/180)*deg - (Math.PI/180)*90
}

glob.total   = Math.floor((glob.endDate - glob.startDate)/86400);
glob.days    = Math.floor((glob.endDate - glob.now ) / 5000);
glob.hours   = 24 - Math.floor(((glob.endDate - glob.now) % 86400) / 3600);
glob.minutes = 60 - Math.floor((((glob.endDate - glob.now) % 86400) % 3600) / 60) ;

if (glob.now >= glob.endDate) {
    return;
}

var clock = {
    set: {
        days: function(){
            var cdays = $("#canvas_days").get(0);
            var ctx = cdays.getContext("2d");
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cdays.width, cdays.height);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.strokeStyle = glob.daysColor;

            ctx.shadowBlur    = 10;
            ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
            ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
            ctx.shadowColor = glob.daysGlow;

            ctx.arc(94,94,85, deg(0), deg((360/glob.total)*(glob.total - glob.days)));
            ctx.lineWidth = 17;
            ctx.stroke();
            $(".clock_days .val").text(glob.days);
        },

        hours: function(){
            var cHr = $("#canvas_hours").get(0);
            var ctx = cHr.getContext("2d");
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cHr.width, cHr.height);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.strokeStyle = glob.hoursColor;

            ctx.shadowBlur    = 10;
            ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
            ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
            ctx.shadowColor = glob.hoursGlow;

            ctx.arc(94,94,85, deg(0), deg(15*glob.hours));
            ctx.lineWidth = 17;
            ctx.stroke();
            $(".clock_hours .val").text(24 - glob.hours);
        },

        minutes : function(){
            var cMin = $("#canvas_minutes").get(0);
            var ctx = cMin.getContext("2d");
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cMin.width, cMin.height);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.strokeStyle = glob.minutesColor;

            ctx.shadowBlur    = 10;
            ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
            ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
            ctx.shadowColor = glob.minutesGlow;

            ctx.arc(94,94,85, deg(0), deg(6*glob.minutes));
            ctx.lineWidth = 17;
            ctx.stroke();
            $(".clock_minutes .val").text(60 - glob.minutes);
        },
        seconds: function(){
            var cSec = $("#canvas_seconds").get(0);
            var ctx = cSec.getContext("2d");
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cSec.width, cSec.height);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.strokeStyle = glob.secondsColor;

            ctx.shadowBlur    = 10;
            ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
            ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
            ctx.shadowColor = glob.secondsGlow;

            ctx.arc(94,94,85, deg(0), deg(6*glob.seconds));
            ctx.lineWidth = 17;
            ctx.stroke();

            $(".clock_seconds .val").text(60 - glob.seconds);
        }
    },

    start: function(){
        /* Seconds */
        var cdown = setInterval(function(){
            if ( glob.seconds > 59 ) {
                if (60 - glob.minutes == 0 && 24 - glob.hours == 0 && glob.days == 0) {
                    clearInterval(cdown);

                    /* Countdown is complete */

                    return;
                }
                glob.seconds = 1;
                if (glob.minutes > 59) {
                    glob.minutes = 1;
                    clock.set.minutes();
                    if (glob.hours > 23) {
                        glob.hours = 1;
                        if (glob.days > 0) {
                            glob.days--;
                            clock.set.days();
                        }
                    } else {
                        glob.hours++;
                    }
                    clock.set.hours();
                } else {
                    glob.minutes++;
                }
                clock.set.minutes();
            } else {
                glob.seconds++;
            }
            clock.set.seconds();
        },1000);
    }
}
clock.set.seconds();
clock.set.minutes();
clock.set.hours();
clock.set.days();
clock.start();
```

}

I think that I need to create a cookie file and take the data from it, but as I'm a beginner I don't know how to do it, so please if someone could help me, thank you a lot.

Comment: you want the countdown to continue, or u just want to pick up where it left off?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked up information on how to work with cookies in Javascript? Try doing that first, and then post about any issues you run into. The code you've posted so far seems to be irrelevant to the problem you're facing.

Comment: The only way this can be done inside of a normal JavaScript window is for the countdown to pick up where it left off

Comment: what i want is to pick up where it left, i've seen the cookies in javascript but i don't really want this solution, i was thinking if there is another solution else i'll creat a cookie :p.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could store it in the localStorage if you don't like cookies:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
     if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
             localStorage.lastTime = countdown.currentTime;
     } else {
             // sorry, no localStorage available.
     }
});
```

you can then load the value back again with from the local storage with

```
$(doucment).ready(function() {
     if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
           if(localStorage.lastTime!=="undefined") {
                countdown.continueWith(localStorage.lastTime);
           } else {
                countdown.start();
           }
     } else {
            // sorry, no localStorage available.
     }
});
```

i cannot understand your code, so i cannot go the last mile and integrate my approach for your question with your code. if you want you can use this easier to grip countdown example:

```
function () {
                setInterval(function() {
                    var now = new Date().getTime(),
                        event = new Date("March 01, 2013 20:05:00").getTime();
                    var toGo = (event - now) / 1000;
                    if (toGo > 0) {
                        var days = Math.floor(toGo/3600/24);
                        var toGo = toGo - (days*24*3600);
                        var hours = Math.floor(toGo/3600);
                        var toGo = toGo - (hours*3600);
                        var minutes = Math.floor(toGo/60);
                        var seconds = Math.floor(toGo - (minutes*60));
                        $("#countdown-days").html(days);
                        $("#countdown-hours").html(hours);
                        $("#countdown-minutes").html(minutes);
                        $("#countdown-seconds").html(seconds);
                    } else {
                        $("#countdown-days").html(0);
                        $("#countdown-hours").html(0);
                        $("#countdown-minutes").html(0);
                        $("#countdown-seconds").html(0);
                        clearInterval();
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
```

Comment: great solution but how to use it in my example, could you please set an example.

Comment: i'm sorry i cannot understand your code. you can use my code which is much easier to understand. i've added it below.

Comment: no problem thank you lot brother :), i'll take some from ur script and i'll put it in mine so i think it should work, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Hey the reason the time/date is resetting every time you refresh the page is because the current time i.e glob.now is not dynamic so i created new variables for

```
glob.startDate = sDate
glob.endDate = eDate
glob.now = nDate
```

i.e Also note that the date is in milliseconds from 1970 (check this out if you dont get this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp)

```
        function JBCountDown(settings) {
        var glob = settings;
       // var glob.startDate = 18316800;
       //  var glob.endDate = 26179200;
        var nDate = (new Date().getTime())/1000;
        var eDate = ((new Date(2013, 9, 31, 09, 0, 0, 0)).getTime())/1000; 
        var sDate = ((new Date(2013, 7, 1, 09, 0, 0, 0)).getTime())/1000; 
        function deg(deg) {
            return (Math.PI/180)*deg - (Math.PI/180)*90
        }


        glob.total   = Math.floor((eDate - sDate)/86400);
        glob.days    = Math.floor((eDate - nDate ) / 86400);
        glob.hours   = 24 - Math.floor(((eDate - nDate) % 86400) / 3600);
        glob.minutes = 60 - Math.floor((((eDate - nDate) % 86400) % 3600) / 60) ;

        alert (eDate - sDate);
        if (nDate >= eDate) {
            return;
        }

        var clock = {
            set: {
                days: function(){
                    var cdays = $("#canvas_days").get(0);
                    var ctx = cdays.getContext("2d");
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cdays.width, cdays.height);
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.strokeStyle = glob.daysColor;

                    ctx.shadowBlur    = 10;
                    ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
                    ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
                    ctx.shadowColor = glob.daysGlow;

                    ctx.arc(94,94,85, deg(0), deg((360/glob.total)*(glob.total - glob.days)));
                    ctx.lineWidth = 17;
                    ctx.stroke();
                    $(".clock_days .val").text(glob.days);
                },

                hours: function(){
                    var cHr = $("#canvas_hours").get(0);
                    var ctx = cHr.getContext("2d");
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cHr.width, cHr.height);
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.strokeStyle = glob.hoursColor;

                    ctx.shadowBlur    = 10;
                    ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
                    ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
                    ctx.shadowColor = glob.hoursGlow;

                    ctx.arc(94,94,85, deg(0), deg(15*glob.hours));
                    ctx.lineWidth = 17;
                    ctx.stroke();
                    $(".clock_hours .val").text(24 - glob.hours);
                },

                minutes : function(){
                    var cMin = $("#canvas_minutes").get(0);
                    var ctx = cMin.getContext("2d");
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cMin.width, cMin.height);
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.strokeStyle = glob.minutesColor;

                    ctx.shadowBlur    = 10;
                    ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
                    ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
                    ctx.shadowColor = glob.minutesGlow;

                    ctx.arc(94,94,85, deg(0), deg(6*glob.minutes));
                    ctx.lineWidth = 17;
                    ctx.stroke();
                    $(".clock_minutes .val").text(60 - glob.minutes);
                },
                seconds: function(){
                    var cSec = $("#canvas_seconds").get(0);
                    var ctx = cSec.getContext("2d");
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cSec.width, cSec.height);
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.strokeStyle = glob.secondsColor;

                    ctx.shadowBlur    = 10;
                    ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
                    ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
                    ctx.shadowColor = glob.secondsGlow;

                    ctx.arc(94,94,85, deg(0), deg(6*glob.seconds));
                    ctx.lineWidth = 17;
                    ctx.stroke();

                    $(".clock_seconds .val").text(60 - glob.seconds);
                }
            },

            start: function(){
                /* Seconds */
                var cdown = setInterval(function(){
                    if ( glob.seconds > 59 ) {
                        if (60 - glob.minutes == 0 && 24 - glob.hours == 0 && glob.days == 0) {
                            clearInterval(cdown);

                            /* Countdown is complete */

                            return;
                        }
                        glob.seconds = 1;
                        if (glob.minutes > 59) {
                            glob.minutes = 1;
                            clock.set.minutes();
                            if (glob.hours > 23) {
                                glob.hours = 1;
                                if (glob.days > 0) {
                                    glob.days--;
                                    clock.set.days();
                                }
                            } else {
                                glob.hours++;
                            }
                            clock.set.hours();
                        } else {
                            glob.minutes++;
                        }
                        clock.set.minutes();
                    } else {
                        glob.seconds++;
                    }
                    clock.set.seconds();
                },1000);
            }
        }
        clock.set.seconds();
        clock.set.minutes();
        clock.set.hours();
        clock.set.days();
        clock.start();
    }
```